# How to pass php variable to include page?

Tags: php, variables

When i load page `index.php`, why not echo `$my_header`

index.php

```
<?php
include 'test.php';
$my_header = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo $my_header; ?>
```

Comment: You have to define `$my_header` before you include your file

Answer (score 1):

Just change the 2 lines like this:

```
$my_header = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
include 'test.php';
```

Also your version should give you an error! if not i would recommend you to turn error reporting on like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

(BTW: i would also recommend you to use `require_once` so the script is only included once and you get errors!)

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Answer (score 0):

define the variable above include file see code below

```
<?php
$my_header = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
include 'test.php';

?>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo $my_header; ?>
```

Comment: can i define include file above variable ?

Comment: if you define variable after the include file at time you code like
<?php echo $my_header; ?> $my_header = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'; so first echo the variable then you define the variable is not worked

Answer (score 0):

Statements are executed in the order they appear. That means that *first* you include a file, which tries to access a variable (which does not yet exist) and *then* you define it, but it is not accessed again.

You have to make sure that you define variables before you try to use them. Like the others say; swap the order of the statement and it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward.

thus, you should set your variable before including the test.php
**option 1:**

*index.php*

```
<?php
  $my_header = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
  include('./test.php');
?>
```

*test.php*

```
<?php
  echo $my_header;
?>
```

you could also achieve this, with changing your test.php to the following

**option 2:**
  *test.php*

```
<?php
  function test($text)
  {
    echo $text;
  }
?>
```

*index.php:*

```
<?php
  include('./test.php');
  $my_header = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
  test($my_header);
?>
```

Comment: could you please give me some example ?

Comment: edited my post to clearify it...

Comment: not work , thank , please give me some code like option2

Comment: the code is already there! what else do you want?

Comment: in option2 : i test load page index.php , but not echo anything .

Comment: but you changed your test.php to what i've posted above?

Comment: it's work thank, and how can i declare php variable in test.php (option 2) like `<?php
  function test($text)
  {
    $sample = $text;
  }
echo $sample;
?>`

Comment: this won't work, because of the variable scope. but before we dig deeper into that, i suggest you start with http://php.net/manual/en/index.php to get the basics!