# How to echo `$var` on this code When load page AAA.php?

Tags: php

How to echo `$var` on this code When load page AAA.php ?

I test this code but not echo `555`

AAA.php

```
<?php
  include('BBB.php');
  $number = 'iii';
  test($number);
?>
```

BBB.php

```
<?php
 function test($numeric)
 {
    if($numeric != '')
    {
        $x = '555';
        return $x;
    }
 }

$var = test($numeric);
echo $var;

?>
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `$numeric`?

Comment: Why should it `echo` 555? What's the value of `$numeric`?

Comment: `$var = test('abc');`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- OP's code makes no sense to me with the variable names and the function and the condition and so on... So if he wants to check if $numeric is numeric ? How knows :D

Comment: @Rizier123 Which is why I posted the link. OP will need to rewrite. This is a basic question checking if data is numeric or not. OP is overthinking it a tad. Right now, OP is only checking if entered data equals nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. -- You're not providing enough details that explain what you actually want to accomplish, or where the variable originates from, or why you think the code isn't working.

Comment: It does echo `555`: https://eval.in/227279

Comment: You know i love puzzles, but i don't get the point, what your goal is!

Comment: `if (!is_numeric ($numeric)){...}` to replace `if($numeric != '')` or `if( $numeric !== null && !is_numeric( $numeric ) ){...}`

Answer (score 2):

Think your looking for something like this:

(Since you want the output `555`)

```
<?php

    function test($numeric) {
        if($numeric != '')
            return "555";
        else
            return false;
    }

    echo $var = test("test");

?>
```

Output:

```
555
```

BTW: i would recommend you 2 things:

for error reporting use this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

And second, this could be helpful to read:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ Rizier123 - not declare `$numeric = "test";`

Comment: @robertderfolo if you don't want to declare it you can enter the string in the function call! (updated my answer)

Comment: @robertderfolo your code makes no sense? Why you call your function 2 times and 1 time with undefined variable?

Comment: @robertderfolo Please explain more what your goal is!

Comment: Where function undefined variable?

Comment: @robertderfolo In the file: `BBB.php` you call the function `test` with $numeric which is undefined!

Comment: @Rizier123 Did you happen to go through OP's other questions which are very similar? Very very very hard to know what the OP wants to achieve. One of those *hard to please* kind of people if you ask me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Did go through it right now! And yes i agree with you :D I remember i tried to answer another question from him(http://stackoverflow.com/q/27165238/3933332) was also a weird question

Comment: @Rizier123 As the saying goes: *"You can please some of the people some of the time, but you can't please all of the people all of the time."* ;) Well, now you know which questions to stay away from. *Cheers*