# How to pass var to include file and then use this var in include file using php , javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How to pass var to include file (`test.php`) and then use this var in include file (`test.php`) ?

First i want to declare var in `main.php` and then i want to pass this var to `test.php` and use this var in `test.php` (EG: `echo` , `if..else`)

I try with php and javascript but not work both , Could you please give me some advice ?

***using PHP***

main.php

```
<?php
  include('test.php');
  $number = '555';
  test($number);
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    function test($numeric) 
    {
       return $sample = $numeric;
    }
echo test($number);
?>
```

***Using JS***

main.php

```
<?php
    include('test.php');
    $number = '555';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    doCallAjax();
</script>
```

test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function doCallAjax() {
        var number = "<?PHP echo $number; ?>";
        alert(number);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your question are so unclear! You will never get an answer if you don't specify your question like: What is the situation/What output do you get? What goal you want to reach/What output do you want? Maybe you read this first and the edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: **javascript** run on your **client** browser, **php** code run on your **server**... send data from js to php via ajax or form post, from php - inject values into html elements and read them using javascript

Comment: @ ymz - you mean use ajax post requests to pass var ?

Comment: Also you ask this question already here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27175733/3933332

Comment: @ Rizier123 - yes, but i not have correct answer

Comment: If you say it here, that's the same question then don't ask it again! wait until you get an answer on your question! Also i would really recommend you to look into a php tutorial or so!(http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php, http://www.w3schools.com/php/) And i can say you, you won't get an answer if you don't specify your question!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share your data on multiple php files, consider to use the global variable or session, so it will be something like this:

SESSION:

main.php:

```
$_SESSION['number'] = '555';
```

test.php:

```
echo $_SESSION['number'];
```

GLOBAL VARIABLES:

main.php

```
global $number;
$number = '555';
```

test.php

```
global $number;
echo $number;
```